# Is there a way to SFINAE based on available overloads in the current class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang, sfinae

I've been using code like this for a while (since GCC 4.9/Clang 3.5 at least):

```
#include <utility>

class foo
{
public:
    void bar(int n);

    template <typename R,
              typename = decltype(std::declval<foo>().bar(*std::begin(std::declval<R>())))>
    void bar(const R& range);
};
```

The point of the second `bar()` overload is it should be SFINAE'd away unless `R` is a range type where an overload of `bar()` exists for its elements.  So `std::vector<int>` would be fine but `std::vector<int*>` wouldn't, for example.

Unfortunately, since Clang 3.9, that gives this error:

```
templ.cpp:12:54: error: member access into incomplete type 'foo'
              typename = decltype(std::declval<foo>().bar(*std::begin(std::declval<R>())))>
                                                     ^
templ.cpp:6:7: note: definition of 'foo' is not complete until the closing '}'
class foo
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this that doesn't rely on using an incomplete type from within its own definition?

Comment: The class is complete within function default arguments, so you could move the SFINAE into a function parameter with a default argument.

Comment: The goal was to stop that template from matching so aggressively.  As a concrete example, `std::string` is a container of `char`s, but I have no overload for `char`, so the template gets skipped, and it picks the `string_view` overload instead.  Without the SFINAE, it would pick the template and then error out.

Comment: You also want `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to work right?  Second, you appear to be missing a `*`.

Comment: @Yakk Ideally yes.  Fixed the missing `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could make foo a default value of additional template parameter:

```
#include <utility>

class foo
{
public:
    void bar(int n);

    template <typename R,
              typename F = foo,
              typename = decltype(std::declval<F>().bar(*std::begin(std::declval<R>())))>
    void bar(const R& range);
};
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HgkzEesjasPI1RXD)

This would delay the check if `foo` is complete.

Comment: be careful as someone could override the value of the typename `F`. you could introduce a variadic in front of it just in case.

Answer (score 2):

The fast and easy way would be to define `bar` in a base class.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename child>
struct base {
    void bar(int);
};

struct foo : base<foo> {
    template<typename R,
              typename = decltype(std::declval<base<foo>>().bar(std::begin(std::declval<R>())))>
    void bar(const R& range);
};
```

But this method can be cumbersome.

Alternatively, if you know what type `bar` need, you can do this:

```
struct foo {
    void bar(int);

    template<typename R,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<int, decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<R>()))>>* = 0>
    void bar(const R& range);
};
```

If `bar` is limited with a constraint, you could use the very same constraint:

```
struct foo {
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<some_contraint<T>::value>* = 0>
    void bar(T);

    template<typename R,
        std::enable_if_t<some_contraint<*std::begin(std::declval<R>())>::value>* = 0>
    void bar(const R& range);
};
```

At last, if you like the last two options, you can encapsulate the range constraint in a type trait:

```
template<typename, typename = void>
struct is_valid_range : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_valid_range<T, std::enable_if_t<some_contraint<*std::begin(std::declval<R>())>::value>> : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make it so that the overload would not be selected if the function's body wouldn't compile.  The trouble is that the compiler needs to make sure that the signature compiles before moving on to the body.

Instead, how about SFINAE'ing based on what you need to be able to do with `R` more specifically?  For example:

```
template<typename R,
         class = decltype(begin(std::declval<const R&>())),
         class = decltype(end(std::declval<const R&>()))>
void bar(const R& range);
```

That way this overload is only selected if you can call `begin` and `end` on a type f `const R&`.

Comment: You're right about what I'm trying to do.  The function's body is something like `for (auto e : range) bar(e);` so I need to check if `bar(e)` is valid, not just whether `R` is a range type at all.

Comment: @TavianBarnes And what does a type need to be able to call `bar(e)`?  You could still check those constraints on the iterator type of `R`.

Comment: The constraint is just whether or not a `bar` overload for that type exists in `foo`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes So then what happens if you call `bar` with a `vector` of elements for which there is no overload?  Shouldn't that be a compilation error?  If so then I would just allow the compilation error to happen.

Comment: No, it should select some other overload if possible.  There may be another viable `bar()` overload, that would bind less tightly than `const R&` because a user-defined conversion would be necessary.  In this case it should use that overload instead of erroring out.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Is there some other overload that takes a range of elements but for which the elements don't need an overload of `bar` to be available?

Comment: Yes, the example I gave above was `string`s, which are a range of `char`s but I handle them separately.  Actually another thing I was using this for was to provide a different implementation for `vector<int*>` than `vector<int>` (checking if `bar(*e)` was viable vs. `bar(e)`)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo;
void free_bar(Foo* foo, int n){
  (void)foo;
  std::cout << n << "\n";
}

class Foo {
public:
  template<class X>
  void bar(X&& x) {
    return free_bar( this, std::forward<X>(x) );
  }
};

template <typename R>
auto free_bar(Foo* foo, const R& range)
-> decltype( free_bar( foo, *std::begin(range) ) )
{
  for (auto&&x:range)
    free_bar(foo, decltype(x)(x));
}
```

This places the `bar` into free functions that take a `Foo*` as their first argument.

The member `.bar(X)` invokes this free function.

ADL means that it does the right thing(tm) usually.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1807ce90211b2113)